# Sever socket doesn't loop

Tags: java, sockets, server, serversocket

I'm currently study on server socket and doing a project on gaming. My game is turn-based 2 player games which will generate 5 random digits and and an answer. Player need to find the math operator( +,-,*,/) for 5 digits that matched the answer. First player will be randomly chosen and when both player finish the round we will compared the time left. Next game the player that has more time left will be first player and game will loop like this forever. So, I write 3 class for handling the game

Sorry for wrong code, I am a newbie to code I don't know where to cut out the code part to ask this question.

For client part I basically send back data from send button.

> This is Server class , which included client handling for multiple client

```
public class serverSocket implements Runnable{
final static int port = 22222;
ServerSocket server;
Socket socket;
boolean play = true;
static int connected = 0;
final static int maxConnected =2;
static int nowplaying;
int firstplayer = (int) (Math.random()*maxConnected);

static List<ClientHandler> connects;
static ArrayList<playerData> players;

static int time1, time2;

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
    new serverSocket(port).run();
}

//start the server.
public serverSocket(int port) {
    GUI();
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("New server initialized!");
        connects = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ClientHandler>());
        players = new ArrayList<playerData>();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //start thread for each client.
    while(connected < maxConnected){
        try {
            socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client " + connected + " is connected.");
            ClientHandler connect = new ClientHandler(socket);
            new Thread(connect).start();
            connects.add(connect);
            connected++;
        } catch (IOException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // first playerData created
    for(int i = 0; i< maxConnected;i++) {
        try {
            players.add((playerData) connects.get(i).clientInput.readObject());
            labelClient.setText(labelClient.getText() + players.get(i).getName() + ", ");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //write back first data to all user.
    writeToALl(players);
    flushALl();
    players.get(firstplayer).setPastWin(true);
}
public void run(){
    for(int i = 0;i< maxConnected;i++) {
        if(players.get(i).getPastWin() == true) {
            try {
                connects.get(i).serverOutput.writeObject(play);
                flushALl();
                nowplaying = i;
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    playerData a = null;
    try {
        a = (playerData) connects.get(nowplaying).clientInput.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(a.getCorrect() == true) {
        time1 = a.getTime();
    }
    try {
        connects.get((nowplaying+1)%maxConnected).serverOutput.writeObject(play);
        flushALl();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    playerData b = null;
    try {
        b = (playerData) connects.get((nowplaying+1)%maxConnected).clientInput.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(b.getCorrect() == true) {
        time2 = b.getTime();
    }
    if(a.getCorrect() == false || time2 > time1) {
        players.get((nowplaying+1)%maxConnected).score++;
        players.get((nowplaying+1)%maxConnected).setPastWin(true);
        players.get((nowplaying+1)%maxConnected).setCorrect(false);
    }
    else if(b.getCorrect() == false || time1>time2) {
        players.get(nowplaying).score++;
        players.get(nowplaying).setPastWin(true);
        players.get(nowplaying).setCorrect(false);
    }
    writeToALl(players);
}

class ClientHandler implements Runnable{

    Socket socket;
    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
    ObjectInputStream clientInput;
    ObjectOutputStream serverOutput;
    public void run() {
        try {
            clientInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            serverOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
public static void writeToALl(Object output) {
    for(int i = 0; i < maxConnected; i++) {
        try {
            connects.get(i).serverOutput.writeObject(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void flushALl() {
    for(int i = 0; i < maxConnected; i++) {
        try {
            connects.get(i).serverOutput.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> this is client side

```
public class clientSocket implements Runnable{
static final int port = 22222;
static Socket socket;
static ObjectInputStream serverInput;
static ObjectOutputStream clientOutput;

static ArrayList<playerData> players;
static playerData playerData;
static boolean nowplay;

static int inputAnswer;
static Timer timer;

static String name;
static int time = 60;
static int score = 0;
static boolean pastplay = false;
static boolean correct = false;

static Random myRandom = new Random();

static int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,givenAnswer;    
static String operator1,operator2,operator3,operator4,result;

public static void main(String[]args){
    new clientSocket("localhost", port).run();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void run(){
    try {
        nowplay = (boolean) serverInput.readObject();
        if(nowplay == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,name + "'s turn");
            timer.start();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        players = (ArrayList<playerData>) serverInput.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    labelScorePlayer1.setText(players.get(0).name + " " + players.get(0).score);
    labelScorePlayer2.setText(players.get(1).name + " " + players.get(1).score);
}
//establish connection with server.
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public clientSocket(String hostname, int port) {
    try {
        GUI();
        socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        clientOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        serverInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        players = new ArrayList<playerData>();
        nowplay = false;
        askName();
        playerData = new playerData(name,score,time, correct, pastplay);
        clientOutput.writeObject(playerData);
        clientOutput.flush();
    } catch (IOException | ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        players = (ArrayList<playerData>) serverInput.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(players.size() > 1) {
        labelScorePlayer1.setText(players.get(0).name + " " + players.get(0).score);
        labelScorePlayer2.setText(players.get(1).name + " " + players.get(1).score);
    }
}





static JFrame frame;
static JPanel panelNorth;
static JPanel panelCenter;
static JPanel panel;
static JPanel panel1;
static JPanel panel2;
static JPanel panelSouth;
static JLabel labelName;
static JLabel labelTimer;
static JLabel labelScorePlayer1;
static JLabel labelScorePlayer2;
static JLabel labelEqual;
static JLabel labelGivenAnswer;
static JLabel labelAnswer;
static JLabel labelInputAnswer;
static JButton buttonNum1;
static JButton buttonNum2;
static JButton buttonNum3;
static JButton buttonNum4;
static JButton buttonNum5;
static JButton buttonSend;
static JButton buttonPlus;
static JButton buttonMinus;
static JButton buttonMultiply;
static JButton buttonDivide;
public static void GUI() throws ScriptException {
    //random integer 0-9.
    num1 = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
    num2 = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
    num3 = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
    num4 = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
    num5 = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
    //random math operator + - * /.
    operator1 = pickRandom();
    operator2 = pickRandom();
    operator3 = pickRandom();
    operator4 = pickRandom();
    //Given answer.
    result = num1 + operator1 + num2 + operator2 + num3 + operator3 + num4 + operator4 + num5;
    givenAnswer = operation(result);
        //GUI
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //panelNorth
    panelNorth = new JPanel();
    panelNorth.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    //game name label
    labelName = new JLabel("IQ180");
    labelName.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    labelName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    //timer
    labelTimer = new JLabel("60");
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playerData.time--;
                time--;
            labelTimer.setText(Integer.toString(time));
            if (time == 0) {
                final Timer timer = (Timer) e.getSource();
                timer.stop();
                time = 60;
            }
        }
    });
    labelTimer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    //adding label to panel
    panelNorth.add(labelName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelNorth.add(labelTimer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //adding panel to frame
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panelNorth);

    //panelCenter
    panelCenter = new JPanel();
    //Score player 1
    labelScorePlayer1 = new JLabel("");
    labelScorePlayer1.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 49);
    labelScorePlayer1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    //Score player2
    labelScorePlayer2 = new JLabel("");
    labelScorePlayer2.setBounds(387, 0, 63, 49);
    labelScorePlayer2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    //adding label to panel
    panelCenter.setLayout(null);
    panelCenter.add(labelScorePlayer1);
    panelCenter.add(labelScorePlayer2);
    //adding panel to frame
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panelCenter);
    //center part of panelCenter 
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(40, 0, 347, 198);
    panelCenter.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    //panel1 inside panel
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBounds(0, 0, 347, 105);
    panel.add(panel1);
    panel1.setLayout(null);
    //button num1
    buttonNum1 = new JButton(Integer.toString(num1));
    buttonNum1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+Integer.toString(num1));
            buttonNum1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    buttonNum1.setBounds(6, 38, 40, 40);
    panel1.add(buttonNum1);
    //button num2
    buttonNum2 = new JButton(Integer.toString(num2));
    buttonNum2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+Integer.toString(num2));
            buttonNum2.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    buttonNum2.setBounds(65, 38, 40, 40);
    panel1.add(buttonNum2);
    //button num3
    buttonNum3 = new JButton(Integer.toString(num3));
    buttonNum3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+Integer.toString(num3));
            buttonNum3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    buttonNum3.setBounds(117, 38, 40, 40);
    panel1.add(buttonNum3);
    //button num4
    buttonNum4 = new JButton(Integer.toString(num4));
    buttonNum4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+Integer.toString(num4));
            buttonNum4.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    buttonNum4.setBounds(169, 38, 40, 40);
    panel1.add(buttonNum4);
    //button num5
    buttonNum5 = new JButton(Integer.toString(num5));
    buttonNum5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+Integer.toString(num5));
            buttonNum5.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    buttonNum5.setBounds(221, 38, 40, 40);
    panel1.add(buttonNum5);
    //equal sign
    labelEqual = new JLabel("=");
    labelEqual.setBounds(273, 37, 10, 40);
    panel1.add(labelEqual);
    //givenAnswerLabel
    labelGivenAnswer = new JLabel(Integer.toString(givenAnswer));
    labelGivenAnswer.setBounds(301, 37, 40, 40);
    panel1.add(labelGivenAnswer);

    //panel2 inside panel
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setBounds(0, 105, 347, 93);
    panel.add(panel2);
    panel2.setLayout(null);
    //plus button
    buttonPlus = new JButton("+");
    buttonPlus.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+"+");
        }
    });
    buttonPlus.setBounds(44, 27, 40, 40);
    panel2.add(buttonPlus);
    //minus button
    buttonMinus = new JButton("-");
    buttonMinus.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+"-");
        }
    });
    buttonMinus.setBounds(120, 27, 40, 40);
    panel2.add(buttonMinus);
    //multiply button
    buttonMultiply = new JButton("*");
    buttonMultiply.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+"*");
        }
    });
    buttonMultiply.setBounds(198, 27, 40, 40);
    panel2.add(buttonMultiply);
    //divide button
    buttonDivide = new JButton("/");
    buttonDivide.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            labelInputAnswer.setText(labelInputAnswer.getText()+"/");
        }
    });
    buttonDivide.setBounds(272, 27, 40, 40);
    panel2.add(buttonDivide);
    //panelSouth
    panelSouth = new JPanel(); // the panel is not visible in output
    labelAnswer = new JLabel("Answer");
    labelInputAnswer = new JLabel("");
    //send button
    buttonSend = new JButton("Send");
    buttonSend.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            String inputAnswer = labelInputAnswer.getText();
            int inputIntAnswer = 0;
            try {
                inputIntAnswer = operation(inputAnswer);
            } catch (ScriptException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(Math.abs(inputIntAnswer-givenAnswer) == 0 && playerData.time > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Correct!");
                labelInputAnswer.setText("");
                playerData.setCorrect(true);
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Wrong!");
                labelInputAnswer.setText("");
            }
            timer.stop();
            playerData.setPastWin(false);
            nowplay = false;
            try {
                clientOutput.writeObject(playerData);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            playerData.time = 60;
            labelTimer.setText(Integer.toString(playerData.time));
            buttonNum1.setEnabled(true);
            buttonNum2.setEnabled(true);
            buttonNum3.setEnabled(true);
            buttonNum4.setEnabled(true);
            buttonNum5.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });
    panelSouth.add(labelAnswer);
    panelSouth.add(labelInputAnswer);
    panelSouth.add(buttonSend);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panelSouth);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}   
//ask name
public static void askName() {
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"What is your name?");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome, " + name);
}
//Get random operator.
public static String getRandom(String[] arr) {        
    int rdm = myRandom.nextInt(arr.length);
    return arr[rdm];
}    
public static String pickRandom() {
    String[] operator = {"+"/*, "-", "*", "/"*/};
    String r = getRandom(operator);
    return r;
}
public static int operation(String input) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();    
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");   
    return new BigDecimal(engine.eval(input).toString()).intValue();
}
```

}

> I'm sending the playerData class back and forth for socket communication.

```
public class playerData implements java.io.Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String name;
int score;
int time;
boolean pastwin;
boolean correct;

public playerData() {
    name = null;
    score = 0;
    time = 60;
    pastwin = false;
    correct = false;
}
public playerData(String name, int score, int time, boolean correct, boolean pastwin) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
    this.time = time;
    this.pastwin = pastwin;
    this.correct = correct;
}
public String toString() {
    return "Name : " + name + ", score : " + score + ", time : " + time;

}
public int getTime(){
    return time;
}
public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public boolean getCorrect() {
    return correct;
}
public boolean getPastWin() {
    return pastwin;
}
public void setTime(int time) {
    this.time = time;
}
public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setPastWin(boolean pastwin) {
    this.pastwin = pastwin;
}
public void setCorrect(boolean correct) {
    this.correct = correct;
}
```

The problem is my run loop doesn't continue after first round and I have no idea why is that happened.

Comment: Which [`while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) condition in your code does not behave as expected? What did you do in the code to get more than one turn? Have you tried to set break point in this specific line and see what happens?

Comment: I use runnable method to loop the turn but it doesn’t work. It stops after both player played their first round.

Comment: The [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread. Thread does not necessarily mean running in a loop. If you want to run the code in the loop you need to make it by using `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [`while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) in the `run` method. If you have any condition to break the `while`, then you can add it in the `while` parenthesis or use `break` in the `while` scope (or both).

```
public void run(){        
  while(true)
  {
        try {
            nowplay = (boolean) serverInput.readObject();
            if(nowplay == true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,name + "'s turn");
                timer.start();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            players = (ArrayList<playerData>) serverInput.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        labelScorePlayer1.setText(players.get(0).name + " " + players.get(0).score);
        labelScorePlayer2.setText(players.get(1).name + " " + players.get(1).score);
  }
}
```